# Оборот с "В случае". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В случае утери или повреждения(,) карточка восстанавливается за дополнительную плату. 
В случае повреждения карточки(,) она восстанавливается за дополнительную плату.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В обоих случаях факультативная постановка запятой, но в тестах **делового характера** запятая обычно не ставится (обычно в таких предложениях оборот стоит в начале предложения).

Дополнительно можно учесть **следующие факторы:** обстоятельственный оборот нераспространенный, структура предложения позволяет прочесть его без обозначенной паузы (интонация простого предложения при отсутствии обособленных членов).

Answer (score 2):

Обстоятельственные обороты **«в случае + существительное»** могут выделяться знаками препинания, *если стоят не в начале и не в конце предложения или находятся между подлежащим и сказуемым, если объясняют смысл высказывания, если указывают на причину, если выделяются интонационно*.

В Вашем случае запятую ставить не нужно.