# Ставится ли запятая? (1)

Tags: запятые

В случае нарушения, материалы видеозаписи будут переданы в уполномоченные органы.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424783/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%92-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5-%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f  повтор вопроса

Comment: @Aer Программа из очереди проверок — **Вопросы на закрытие** — почему-то (с трёх раз!) не даёт мне возможности "поучаствовать" в этом деле. Я в чём-то провинилась?

Answer (score 1):

[Розенталь Д.Э. Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114) 
 Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения ***могут*** обособляться обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова.

...Чаще всего обособленные обстоятельственные конструкции образуются существительными с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями: *благодаря, ввиду, в зависимости, во избежание, вопреки, в отличие, в противоположность, в связи с, в силу, вследствие, в случае, за неимением, за отсутствием, несмотря на, подобно, по причине, по случаю, при, при наличии, при условии, согласно* и др. Например: ...***Я стал на углу площадки, крепко упершись левой ногою в камень и наклонясь немного вперёд, чтобы, в случае лёгкой раны, не опрокинуться назад*** (Л.)

Обособить *в случае нарушения* можно, чтобы выделить смысл выражения. Но и без запятой предложение выглядит нормально.